# AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying insert data in a DATE format at database using SqlAlchemy, the problem is when I go check the database, there are only NULL values.

How to Insert Timestamp data into MySQL db using python/SqlAlchemy.

AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'translate'.

Data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import MySQLdb

import json
import datetime
import time


# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({ "year" : [ "2017/10/10", "2018/10/10", "2019/10/10"]
```

my code:

```
# transforming to datetime
df.year = pd.to_datetime(df.year)

out[]: 
year   datetime64[ns]



#adding in list of dict to be able to insert at db

values_list2 = []   
for i in range(len(df)):
    values_list2.append({ "Rece_Year": df["year"][i] })



# create table in db with Datetime column format

data = db.Table('Test', metadata,                
              db.Column('Rece_Year',  db.DateTime(), default=True),                                      
              extend_existing=True 
              )


metadata.create_all(engine)

#Insert data
query = db.insert(data)
```

If I use `String`, it works. but I need in a DATE format

```
data = db.Table('Test', metadata,                 
              db.Column('Rece_Year',  db.String(100), nullable=True),                                      
              extend_existing=True 
              )


metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: Have you tried pandas native function `DataFrame.to_sql`?

Comment: @Erfan nop, let me try this..

Comment: @Parfait, I updated the question ``` db = SqlAlchemy```  as you can check at the import

Comment: Please show output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Test` so we can see your table schema. Also what is *metadata*? Please set up [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed the Data type in the db itself, and it worked. So it seems it was a issue with SqlAlchemy packaging, not sure.

So it is not really an answer, but that is what I got to work unfortunately.